# Python increment value by 100 while true

Tags: python, increment

```
 if 150 <= center_x <= 180:
            x = 200
            x += 100
            MESSAGE = str(x)
```

I'm running this statement. While true I want x to increment by 100 thus outputting: 300, 400, 500, 600 700, etc

For some reason, my output is 300, 300, 300, 300 etc..

How do I fix this? (Thanks in Advance) : )

Comment: You're resetting x to 200 every time. Move that line somewhere else outside the statement.

Comment: you need to keep ```x = 200``` outside. as its resetting everytime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that this block of code is inside of a *while True* loop. If so, then the problem is that you are setting *x* to 200 at each itteration and then incrementing it by 100, giving 300 on each iteration. You should give your starting value to *x* outside of the loop.

Comment: You're a genius

Answer (score 2):

```
#First you need to define your center_x. You may get this value from some other
#function in your script. I will use 160 as a valid example
center_x  = 160

#You need to define initial value of x outside of the loop so it does not "reset"
x = 200
if 150 <= center_x <= 180:
    while x <= 600: #Here you set the limit of where you want to stop adding. I used 600 as example
        x += 100
        print(x) #There is no need to set a MESSAGE variable, you can directly print the x variable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to something like:

```py
x = 200
if 150 <= center_x <= 180:
    x += 100
    MESSAGE = str(x)
```